# How to set UpdatePanel to automatically update while registering AsyncPostBackTrigger programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a Button which will trigger an UpdatePanel, but it is in a different container so if I put my code like below :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uptxtQuickSearch" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" style="height: 100%;">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuickSearch" CssClass="textinput" onmouseover="this.select()" onfocus="this.select()" onkeydown="QuickSearch()" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearchFilter" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There will be a runtime server error : "A control with ID 'btnSearchFilter' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'uptxtQuickSearch'."

So I've to register it on the Page_load event with ScriptManager :

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btnSearchFilter);
```

but in this case, I still have to update the UpdatePanel manually by using Update() method on the end of btnSearchFilter_click event.
Is there any way to update the panel automatically while registering the trigger on the code-behind?

Comment: If possible, I would encourage you to move away from updatepanels and the old way of doing ajax in asp.net. I find that it's much more manageable to do your ajax in javascript.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, did you mean like using jQuery.ajax method? I know it's resources-wise but I can't see the "much more manageable" part of it, can you help me find a site that explain it in details?

Comment: There are several tutorials online. Here is one example: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery--net-6289

Comment: The downside to updatepanels/asp.net ajax toolkit is that it abstracts ajax to the point where many developers don't fully grasp the concept of it. I also find it to be inflexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this issue. It turns out that you don't really need to register the control using `RegisterAsyncPostBackControl` method.

you just need to add the trigger on `Page_Init` event and use the `control.UniqueID` if the control cannot be found on the runtime.

So the aspx will be like this :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uptxtQuickSearch" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" style="height: 100%;">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuickSearch" CssClass="textinput" onmouseover="this.select()" onfocus="this.select()" onkeydown="QuickSearch()" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in code-behind :

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uptxtQuickSearch.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger() { ControlID = btnSearchFilter.UniqueID });
}
```